# Why asyncController failed to fetching data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, task

Here I'm new to `AsyncController` please help me why I'm not able to fetch data from db by using async:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
 {
     Task<IEnumerable<Country>> objctry = Task.Factory.StartNew<IEnumerable<Country>>(objrepo.GetCountry);
      await Task.WhenAll(objctry);
      return View(objctry);
 }
```

If I change above code as:

```
 public ActionResult Index() { var x = objrepo.GetCountry();return View(x); }
```

Its working.
Please guide me where exactly i'm doing wrong

Comment: You are doing wrong by awaiting `StartNew` (or `Task.Run`) in asp.net controller, making the whole thing absolutely useless. It's better (I mean for perfomance) to not use async\await at all than use like this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using [`Task.WhenAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160374(v=vs.110).aspx) incorrectly in this case.

Use [`Task.Run`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.run(v=vs.110).aspx) and refactor the action as follows

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index() {
    IEnumerable<Country> objctry = await Task.Run(() => objrepo.GetCountry);
    return View(objctry);
}
```